# Python array from a JSON file

Tags: python, arrays

I have a JSON file with data that i want to convert into an array using python however the JSON file from which the information comes from has too many blocks of information.

```
import json

jsonString = '{"player":1,"position"{"Traveled":400,"distanceLeft":100,}"Position":1}'

aDict = json.loads(jsonString)
print(aDict)
print(aDict['position'])
```

This code works until i want to have more players it stops working.

What i want to do is to be able to search for any player and have the stats printed.
I get the error "extra data" when i try to have all players be in the file.

```
"1":{"player":1,"position":{"Traveled":400,"distanceLeft":100,}"Position":1}
"2":{"player":2,"position":{"Traveled":300,"distanceLeft":200,}"Position":2}
"3":{"player":3,"position":{"Traveled":200,"distanceLeft":300,}"Position":3}
"4":{"player":4,"position":{"Traveled":100,"distanceLeft":400,}"Position":4}
"5":{"player":5,"position":{"Traveled":0,"distanceLeft":500,}"Position":5}
```

Edit:

i changed it and the code now looks like this:

```
 #read file
with open('data.json', 'r') as myfile:
  data = myfile.read()
  

aDict = json.loads(data)
print(aDict)
print(aDict['1'])
```

it reads the file fine but im getting the error message:

JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Comment: Your code does *not* work, since the `jsonString` is not valid JSON.

Comment: can you print the actual console log which you get on error. Also if possible share the whole data file so that we can help you better.

Comment: How would you solve the problem of organizing this data, if it *weren't* anything to do with JSON? You would have a bunch of dicts, each of which represents a player; and you would want to store all those dicts together somehow... like... in a list, perhaps?

Comment: "it reads the file fine but im getting the error message" Okay, well then this is simply a question of understanding the JSON file format, and paying close attention. You should probably not be trying to create the file by hand. Instead, try to have it come from creating a data structure and using `.dump` on it. Incidentally, rather than `.read`ing the file yourself and using `.loads` on the string, you can `.load` directly from the file. That's why there are both methods.